# Updated to Xcode 5.1.1 causes strange crash of iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, jquery-mobile, cordova

Unfortunately I auto-updated Xcode to Version 5.1.1 (5B1008), and now one of my apps crashes in a very strange way.

The app is a PhoneGap 3.4 (+ jQuery Mobile 1.3.1) hybrid app, the crash happens when I try to open a JQM page that contains ~20 JQM checkbox.

The crash happens in `CoreGraphics CGPathAddLineToPoint` called by `WebCore WebCore::RenderThemeIOS::paintCheckboxDecorations` in the `WebThread`, I guess when WebCore attempts to render the checkboxes on then JQM page.

The console reads:

`Assertion failed: (CGFloatIsValid(x) && CGFloatIsValid(y)), function void CGPathAddLineToPoint(CGMutablePathRef, const CGAffineTransform *, CGFloat, CGFloat), file Paths/CGPath.cc, line 224.
(lldb)`

Any other JQM page NOT containing checkboxes is displayed properly, and it does not crash the app.

EDIT: interestingly, the crash is triggered by this line of Javascript:

`$('#my_checkbox').prop("checked", my_boolean_value).checkboxradio("refresh");`

If I disable it, the JQM page shows up. But then, even if the above line is disabled, if I click on any checkbox, it crashes again, with the same above `Assertion failed` message. (I guess because JQM toggles the check/unchecked class.)

I already performed all the tricks I could think of (clean, disable debugger, reboot, reinstalled Xcode), with no luck.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: The most I could find out about this type of crash bug is that it only happens if it's trying to draw while an animation is in progress. However, since it's an assert failure and not an uncaught exception, the only thing you can do is avoid running the offending code, which may be problematic if the code is entirely inside libraries you can't modify. If your crash bug is anything like mine... then maybe there's an animation going on somewhere that could be disabled?  Otherwise I have nothing to offer; this type of crash is its own kind of evil.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed, after spending one day trying to figure it out, I will resolve to change my design in order not to trigger the "offending" code --- since my app is hybrid, I really cannot control the details of the interaction between the JS/CSS and WebCore.

Comment: I "accept" my own answer below, because there is nothing that can be done except prevent the bug to be triggered. (And hope Apple will fix WebCore.)

Comment: [They may get around to it](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5158267).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the following **very irritating** fact: the crash is triggered by a

```
opacity:.01
```

directive, attached to the JQM `.ui-checkbox` class in my CSS.

Changing it to:

```
opacity:0
```

prevents the crash (which I still do not know if it is due to an Xcode bug or an iOS bug).

Interestingly, setting **any** value greater than `0` triggers the crash.

Comment: While changing the opacity prevented the crash, there is a deeper issue, related to using an invalid context. I get the same error also, followed by a long list of warnings related to "using an invalid context and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability."

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue,but it was caused by an attributed text link. I ended up having to change "Continue..." to "Continue"